# Нективное окно в C#

Tags: c#

Добрый день всем.

У меня возникла такая проблема. Хочу сделать неактивным окно в C#, пишу следующий код:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Enabled = false;
```

компилятор не выдает ошибок, но окно остается активным. Помогите, что исправить или написать?

Comment: Какой результат вы хотите получить? Что по вашему "сделать неактивной форму"? Могу ошибаться, но с формой так работать нельзя: "Forms that are not enabled cannot be displayed".

Comment: Хочу, чтобы нельзя было клацать по кнопкам в родительской форме. ну, написано, что свойство формы Enabled установить на false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите заблокировать все элементы формы 1, но оставить ее видимой, то это делается так:

```
Form2 newForm = new Form2(); 
        newForm.ShowDialog();
```

Пробуйте.

Answer (score 1):

Пример, который вы написали не выведет форму на экран. Если у Вас при этом форма на экране видна, то осмеливаюсь предположить, то вы делаете неактивной не ту форму, которую хотите. Так рекомендую найти тот экземпляр формы, которые вам требуется сделать неактивной и для него установить свойство `Enabled` в `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать форму `Enabled=false` после того, как она появилась на экране. У меня точно работало.